# Playing AVI with PHP readfile()

Tags: php, video-streaming, avi

I have embeded player in  HTML:

```
<OBJECT id=WindowsMediaPlayer1 width=320 height=264 hspace=5
vspace=5 classid=clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6 border="5" align="middle" >
<param name="URL" value="http://www.my.domain/stream.php">

<EMBED type='application/x-mplayer2'
pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1'
bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1'
showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="320" height="264"
src="http://www.my.domain/stream.php" autostart="0" designtimesp='5311'>
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

stream.php

```
<?php
$path='/path/to/file/my.avi';
header('Content-type: video/x-msvideo');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));
readfile($path);
?>
```

video is playing when: src="http://www.my.domain/my.avi
video is not playing when: src="http://www.my.domain/stream.php (no pictures)

P.S. mp4,flv,mov works

can you help me?

lubo

Answer (score 2):

I think it's all in the headers... found a tutorial online.. http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Video-Streaming-PHP-Script-Tutorial/3/

In the tutorial that guy used:

```php
header('Content-type: video/mpeg');    
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size    
header("Expires: -1");    
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");    
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);    
readfile($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the location header instead:

```
$path='/path/to/file/my.avi';
header("location: $path");
```

Comment: video still not play,this will download AVI

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are sending the wrong content-type header.  It is generally necessary to get that header right, if you want the client to know what type of content it is.

You can verify this by using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and comparing the headers from when the file is accessed directly, vs. when access via your script.

Comment: Fiddler said:Content-Type: video/x-msvideo. - in case direct playing

Answer (score -1):

simple solution... Make a mp4, mov or flv file, use that within your website